# How to get users, bots and online users number in discord.net?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I am making a bot that shows stats of the server but I don't want the voice channel to change two thousand times an hour as the existing bots do. My only problem is how to get the number of bots, users and users with specific statuses. I tried `_discord.Guilds.Count` but it shows only the amount of users + bots. Thank you in advance ^^

Comment: I’ve run into this too. When I download the guild users, all I see is my bot user, not my personal user logged into the guild. And the socket client IGuild.DownloadUsersAsync call never returns.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to foreach through all memebers and get their status.

Firstly remember to enable  `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` in your bot settings under `https://discord.com/developers/applications/<your application id here>/bot`
[That button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA2zy.png)

```
            IGuild guild = _discord.GetGuild(1234567890); //Put your discord server id
            IGuildUser[] users = guild.GetUsersAsync().Result.ToArray();
            int totalUsers = users.Where(user => user.IsBot == false).Count();
            int online = 0;
            int offline = 0;
            int bots = 0;
            foreach (IGuildUser user in users)
            {
                if (user.IsBot) bots++;
                else if (user.Status == UserStatus.Online) online++;
                else if (user.Status == UserStatus.Offline) offline++;
            }
```

You can also try to add some delays between get methods if bot return nulls, like `await Task.Delay(5000)` or `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`